# Listview two items selected while scrolling

Tags: android, listview

I am facing issue in **multiselect listview** and issue i am facing was when i select the first item in the listview last item also checked while scrolling and this issue happens only if i have more that 10+ items in listview. I don't know what's wrong in my code and could any one suggest me a proper solution to avoid this problem.Thanks in advance

```
private class MultipleChoiceClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        if (questionCount > 0) {
            ImageView imgTick = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgTick);
            int len = lvMultiSelect.getCount();
            checked = lvMultiSelect.getCheckedItemPositions();
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (i == position) {
                    if (checked.get(i)) {
                        lvMultiSelect.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(
                                getResources().getColor(
                                        R.color.listitem_onclick));
                        imgTick.setImageResource(R.drawable.tick_img);
                    } else {
                        lvMultiSelect.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(
                                getResources().getColor(
                                        R.color.default_list_background));
                        imgTick.setImageResource(R.drawable.not_checked_img);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It may be because the use of cached view. Possible solution is to maintain the checked and unchecked status in a model class. And refer the object of model class to set the check and uncheck status in view

Answer (score 0):

Create an object to store the position of all tags something like Integer array.

In your `onItemClick`, try this:

`checked = view.getTag();`

and once you select an item, do `view.setTag(positions);`. But nevertheless I suggest you, switch to `RecyclerView` if this codebase is new / you are doing it from scratch.

Answer (score -2):

I have done this using `RecyclerView Multiselect` using `Contextual Action Mode`. Check this.